# PageController's jumpToPage does not work properly when PageView is used as children of TabBarView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The normal method of using PageController's jumpToPage to jump to the specified page is feasible.

But when I switch between Tabs and use the PageController's jumpToPage method in the Tab's onTap method to jump to the specified page, the specified page will appear briefly (for example, specifying index 3 of ThumbnailWidget), and then will be replaced by the widget with index 0 Dropping it, such as the CustomTableWidget in the code below, will cause flickering.

My goal is that after switching the Tab page, the page specified by PageController's jumpToPage can be displayed normally.

The following is my code implementation:

- It should be noted that each table has four pages, listViewPage, timelinePage, chatViewPage, and thumbnailPage, which can be switched, and the variables that record the page index in each table are saved in the TableModel.
- The setViewIndex method of tableModel is used to update the page index saved in the table, and is only used in the following code

```dart
class _TableTabState extends State<TableTabWidget> {
  double itemHeight = 28;
  final PageController pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageViewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setViewIndex(int index) {
    pageViewController.jumpToPage(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TreeModel>(
      builder: (context, treeModel, child) => DefaultTabController(
        length: treeModel.tables.length,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
                    tabs: treeModel.tables
                        .map((table) => Tab(
                              height: 24,
                              child: Text('${table.title}(${table.count})'),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    onTap: (index) {
                      /// Switch tab page
                      Provider.of<TreeModel>(context, listen: false)
                          .selectTable(index);
                      /// Jump to the page specified by PageController
                      if (pageViewController.hasClients) {
                        setViewIndex(treeModel.tables[index].viewIndex);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 24,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: _buildMenuAnchor(),
                  ),
                ]),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: treeModel.tables.map((table) {
                  return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                    value: table,
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: pageViewController,
                      children: [
                        const CustomTableWidget(),
                        const TimelineWidget(),
                        const ChatViewWidget(),
                        const ThumbnailWidget(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<String> menuAnchorList = ['listViewPage', 'timelinePage', 'chatViewPage', 'thumbnailPage'];
  Widget _buildMenuAnchor() {
    late MenuController? menuController;
    return Consumer<TreeModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
      return MenuAnchor(
        builder: (BuildContext context, MenuController controller, _) {
          menuController = controller;
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (controller.isOpen) {
                controller.close();
              } else {
                controller.open();
              }
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  menuAnchorList[model.selectedTable == null
                      ? 0
                      : model.selectedTable!.viewIndex],
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                ),
                const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        menuChildren: List<Widget>.generate(menuAnchorList.length, (index) {
          bool isDisabled = false;
          if (model.tables.isNotEmpty &&
              menuAnchorList[index] == 'chatViewPage' &&
              !model.selectedTable!.type.contains('message')) {
            isDisabled = true;
          }
          return SizedBox(
            height: 24,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: isDisabled
                  ? null
                  : () {
                      /// Switching PageView here is feasible
                      model.selectedTable!.setViewIndex(index);
                      setViewIndex(index);
                      if (menuController != null && menuController!.isOpen) {
                        menuController!.close();
                      }
                    },
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  menuAnchorList[index],
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I'm hoping to resolve the conflict between PageView and Tab, does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the same `PageController` is being used for every tab.

How about creating a dedicated `PageController` for each tab?

For example:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class _TableTabState extends State<TableTabWidget> {
  double itemHeight = 28;
  final List<PageController> pageViewControllers = [];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final controller in pageViewControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setViewIndex({
    required int tabIndex,
    required int viewIndex,
  }) {
    pageViewControllers[tabIndex].jumpToPage(viewIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TreeModel>(
      builder: (context, treeModel, child) => DefaultTabController(
        length: treeModel.tables.length,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              ...,
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
                  tabs: treeModel.tables
                      .map((table) => Tab(
                            height: 24,
                            child: Text('${table.title}(${table.count})'),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  onTap: (index) {
                    /// Switch tab page
                    Provider.of<TreeModel>(context, listen: false)
                        .selectTable(index);

                    /// Jump to the page specified by PageController
                    if (pageViewControllers[index].hasClients) {
                      setViewIndex(
                        tabIndex: index,
                        viewIndex: treeModel.tables[index].viewIndex,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
                ...,
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: treeModel.tables.mapIndexed((index, table) {
                  final pageViewController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
                  pageViewControllers.add(pageViewController);
                  return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                    value: table,
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: pageViewController,
                      children: [
                        ...,
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tanks for anwser, this can solve my question